# For Each block in Specific Context in Java

Tags: java

I am an eighth grader on a mission to create an application in Java that finds the point where two virtual lines meet, given the slope and y-intercept of the two lines.  As it stands right now, I have two arrays (both with long values) that store the y values for the given x values (x = 0, 1, 2, etc).  Now I need to figure out how to create a for each block (you know, the one with the colon in it) to check if the y value in the first array is equal to its counterpart in the other array.  How do I do this?

Comment: What is tricky about this is that a `foreach` loop iterates only over a single entity, but you are trying to iterate over multiple entities (both arrays at the same time).  It is clear how to do that with a conventional `for` loop, but not with a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Oh, so like the answer below (with the upvote), right?

Comment: Yes, but if you were specifically asked for a `foreach` loop, you'll need some other kind of solution.

Comment: @CarlManaster Can't say I know a whole lot about Java, so I really don't care what I use, as long as in the end the code works and it is easy to read/efficient.

Comment: Then @Binyamin's solution is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have two arrays, you should probably use a normal loop, and not a for-each loop. Something like:

```
// assuming both arrays are of the same size
for (int i = 0; i < firstArr.length; ++i) {
    if (firstArr[i] == secondArr[i]) {
        // match found
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point...  I see what you mean here, thank you!  I will accept it when it is possible, unless a better answer arises.  +1

Comment: @D3mon-1stVFW He answered my question, even though he may have pointed me in a different direction.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

If you have both the x and y in arrays type Long just do

```
findIntersect:
  for(Long x : xArray){
    for(Long y : yArray){
      if(x==y){
        System.out.println("They do intersect");
        break findIntersect; //leave loop
      }
    }
  }
```

sorry for missing that part.

**End edit**

```
List<Long> xList; //Assuming it has 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

for(Long x : xList){
  Long y1 = giveMePointYBasedOnSlope1(x);
  Long y2 = giveMePointYBasedOnSlope2(x);

  if(y1 == y2){
    System.out.println("They do intersect");
    break; //leave loop
  }
}

//Example slope1 :  y = (x * 2) + 3
public Long giveMePointYBasedOnSlope1(Long x){
  return (x*2) + 3;
}

//Example slope2 :  y = (x * -.5) + 7    
public Long giveMePointYBasedOnSlope2(Long x){
  return (x * -0.5) + 7;
}
```

Comment: Confusing...  But okay.. I guess

Comment: I thought it will be the easiest to understand, assuming you have decent math. You use the slope to create the y point.  Since you have a set of x points, then you just create the y and if it is the same then they intersect.

Comment: I meant confusing more in terms of the code formatting (long variable names, and the like).  I understand the math part, but it took me a while.  +1

Comment: I see the edit, it does make a bunch more sense now.  Thank you!

Comment: From RL examples and working on projects that are 200k+ lines of code I can assure you that the more the function name says the easier it will be to understand what it is doing just like reading a sentence it saves at least 2 minutes\function.  You just know what it is supposed to do without looking at the code.

Comment: True, very true.  Wish more people used longer variable names than "a" or "g"...  Kids these days...  :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to comment on the algorithm , but it seems like for your use case the for-each block isn't a good fit. Apart from the fact that for-each blocks don't lend themselves well to multiple collections, you potentially might also have the problem of arrays being of different sizes.

You are better off using a loop like the following

```
for(int i = 0;i < firstArr.length && i < secondArr.length;i++) {
  //Your comparison logic here
}
```

What this loop is doing is that it only goes until the end of the smaller of the 2 arrays.

Comment: Okay, thank you.  So basically the same as the answer by Binyamin Sharet, right?